# custom Laravel Validation Rule example

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to write a custom validation rule in Laravel 5.1. I've read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules), but it seems incomplete. Looking it over, I just don't see where I'm supposed to put my actual validation logic, such as `if (stristr($string, 'test')) { ...` and so on.

For another thing, it doesn't show in what method/array the error message defintions should go:

```
"foo" => "Your input was invalid!",

"accepted" => "The :attribute must be accepted.",

// The rest of the validation error messages...
```

My actual use case is somewhat strange, so for this question, let's use the example of validating a secure password. A secure password must be at least 8 characters long, containing a lowercase and uppercase letter, a number and a special character.

Actually, that's a pretty tall order for an example, so how about just checking for a number? Or running any string function on the value?

How would one create such a validation rule?

Comment: Have you checked this links - https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules ? it's quite easier to add new custom validation

Comment: @Jobayer I literally linked that in my question.

Comment: I think if someone want to validate with something not in the form will struggle with this. I'm looking for the answer as well.

Comment: I figure it out using "Manually Creating Validators" with After Validation Hook

Answer (score -1):

As described in the [document you've linked](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#custom-validation-rules), you need to put your validation logic inside the `boot` function of a `ServiceProvider`, (e.g. `AppServiceProvider`) by using the static `extend` method.

Here is a short example (associated with the example in the docs).

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('yourFunctionNameHere', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return $value == 'yourTestValueHere'; //change the body as you need it
        });
    }
}
```

The input of the user is assigned to `$value`

Comment: This is what I don't understand-- where do I actually test the value? Where do I put something like `if (strlen($string)) < 12 ) {...`?

Comment: The value is the text/string inserted by the user ;)

Comment: Have you actually made your own custom validation, or are you just copying from the documentation? Your example doesn't answer the question I posed.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/data-validation-laravel-right-way-custom-validators/ has exactly what you need. There are a few differences that I do when I need something like this, but it will get you going. Just a matter of how you want to structure it.

Comment: @AndrewNolan Thanks so much for this. Care to make it an answer? I will accept it.

Comment: Not truly my answer, but I have a few custom validation rules that extends the validator. Mine has a few minor differences. If I have the time, I can post one of my own examples.

Comment: @AndrewNolan well it is a link to a working example, which is better than the docs. That's what I was looking for. I'd like to accept yours, while I can post my example, also.

Comment: @user151841 My example is also a working one ^^ The example I gave IS a custom validation function you can use when validating your forms..